# Help me to translate 지치고 고된 퇴근 후에

Tags: translation

How to put this sentence in english?
지치고 고된 퇴근 후에

Is it alright if i make it into this: 'after a hard day and leaves work'. It's sounds weird to put it altogether though..

Edit: the next sentence is 집에 도착한 나를 반겨주는 건..... 
Maybe it would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a full sentence, so one will require a better context to get a better translation.

One can start from a simple "After a hard day at work." If the main clause of the sentence describing some action of an agent immediately follows, then maybe I would try something like "After a hard day at work, exhausted, (they walked in to a bar.)"

*퇴근* may mean just leaving work (walking out of your office after a day's work), or it may imply the agent *arrived home* after a day's work. So, also depending on the surrounding context, it can go like "As X arrived home after a hard day (at work), they were so exhausted, (hardly able to prepare their own dinner.)" Maybe one can omit *at work* here, if it is clear from the context.

There are so many possible ways to make a natural sentence, but each one must assume a certain context, much more than you provided. Hopefully you know how to figure it out. At least 'after a hard day and leaves work' isn't grammatical.

### EDIT

If it helps, let me leave some notes on Korean vocabulary.

"퇴근" (n.) means leaving work. Not quitting, but just leaving your workplace after a day of work. As noted above, one might say "퇴근" only after arriving home, but that is not a must.

"고되다" (adj.) means hard, arduous, or tough. Maybe physically. The first few things that match my own image of some "고된 일" would be manual labor and military training.

"지치다" (v.) means to get exhausted and tired. One can "지치다" from work, from their partner's lies, from working out, a long and boring lecture, ...

In fact, to be very critical, the expression is not fully grammatically correct in Korean. From the structure it seems like "고되고 지친" modifies "퇴근", but that doesn't make sense. But I believe most native speakers of Korean won't be that critical with this sentence, and naturally understand it like "고된 일을 마치고 지친 채로 퇴근한 후에". Actually the given expression sounds quite natural to me, not in the sense that it is somewhat *proper* but that one can imagine a native speaker making the expression in natural speech.

Comment: Yeah, i'm not really sure if i should use the exact word "leave work" because the next part says "arrived/get home"

Comment: As you added the next part of the sentence, then I would say "What welcomes me after I get home after a hard day at work is ..." Or maybe "X welcomes me after (and the same follows.)"